# Añadir registro en una tabla con llave foranea en Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo una tabla Personas y otra Alumnos, Alumnos depende de Personas por lo cual quiero saber como puedo registrar a un nuevo Alumno.
No sé cómo puedo insertar un registro en Alumnos, ya que a la vez tendría que ingresar uno en la tabla persona y conseguir el id de la persona para crear al alumno, no lo entiendo muy bien aún.
Acepto también opiniones sobre mi código, tal vez no sea la mejor forma de hacerlo, pero separé los datos así para no tener los campos generales de nombre, apellido, sexo, etc en varias tablas ya que tengo 3 tipos de personas y puede que tenga más en el futuro.

Esto es lo que tengo en las migrations y los modelos de Eloquent:

**PERSONAS MIGRATION**

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('PERSONAS', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->integer('dni')->unique();
            $table->string('nombres', 50);
            $table->string('apePaterno', 35);
            $table->string('apeMaterno', 35);
            $table->char('sexo', 1);
            $table->string('celular', 10)->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('telefono', 10);
            $table->string('correo', 50)->unique();
            $table->string('direccion', 150)->nullable();
            $table->string('distrito', 35)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

**PERSONA MODEL**

```php
class Persona extends Model
{
    public function profesor(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Profesor','idProfesor');
    }

    public function apoderado(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Apoderado','idApoderado');
    }

    public function alumno(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Alumno','idAlumno');
    }
}
```

**ALUMNOS MIGRATION**

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ALUMNOS', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('idPersona');
            $table->foreign('idPersona')->references('id')->on('PERSONAS')->onUpdate('CASCADE');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('idApoderado');
            $table->foreign('idApoderado')->references('id')->on('APODERADOS')->onUpdate('CASCADE');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('idSeccion');
            $table->foreign('idSeccion')->references('id')->on('SECCIONES')->onUpdate('CASCADE');

            $table->string('colegioPrecedencia', 50)->nullable();
            $table->integer('numHermanos')->nullable();
            $table->string('viveCon', 50)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('saleSolo');
            $table->string('nomTrasporte', 50)->nullable();
            $table->string('numTrasporte', 15)->nullable();
            $table->string('observaciones', 200)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**ALUMNO MODEL**

```php
class Alumno extends Model
{
    public function persona(){

        return $this->belongTo('App\Persona', 'idPersona');
    }

    public function apoderado(){

        return $this->belongTo('App\Apoderado', 'idApoderado');
    }

    public function alumno(){

        return $this->belongTo('App\Alumno', 'idAlumno');
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que has intentado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me pasó lo mismo cuando tenia relaciones que dependen de otras, lo pude solucionar de manera relativamente fácil, te dejo un ejemplo adaptado a tu código.

### Según tu modelo

```
$infoPersona = [
    'dni' => 12345678,
    'nombres' => 'Juanito',
    'apePaterno' => 'Perez',
    'apeMaterno' => 'Machuca',
    'sexo' => 'M',
    'telefono' => '123456789',
    'direccion' => 'Cajon del Maipo 255',
    'distrito' => 'Santiago',
];

$infoAlumno = [
    'idApoderado' => 1,
    'idSeccion' => 1,
    'colegioPrecedencia' => 'Machuca',
    'numHermanos' => 2,
    'saleSolo' => true,
];

$persona = Persona::create($infoPersona);
$persona->alumno()->create($infoAlumno);
```

Conste que eso solo funcionará si tienes el id del apoderado y la sección.

***¿Cómo funciona?***

Al crear primero la persona ya te genera un id, como tiene una relación en el modelo, al llamarla y enviarle los datos, te la crea y asigna la id de la persona automáticamente.

Saludos :D

Comment: ¡Gracias totales!